# Can I get job & residence permit in another EU country if my status is as per Portugal's law - article 88 para 2

Tags: resident-permit, eu, residency, residence-cards, portugal

My Portugal employer wants my entry to Portugal through a Schengen - Business visa, then applying for a residence permit from Portugal in accordance to article 88 para 2, RESIDENCE PERMIT FOR EMPLOYED WORKERS WITHOUT A RESIDENCE VISA.

My question is if I acquire residence permit this way, will I be able to -

- Apply for a new residence permit from another EU country if I have to change jobs?
- Participate in university education with that residence permit

Comment: What sort of university education are you thinking of pursuing?

Comment: I have some incomplete credits that I wanted to complete enrolling in a university on a part-time basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Apply for a new residence permit from another EU country if I have to change jobs?

You can of course apply, just as you are able to apply for a residence permit in Portugal. 
 But you will not automatically receive a residence or work permit in another EU or Schengen country on the basis of your authorization to reside or work in Portugal.  After you have lived in Portugal for five years, however, that changes, under [Directive 2003/109/EC concerning the status of third-country nationals who are long-term residents](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02003L0109-20110520).

> Participate in university education with that residence permit

Authorized foreign workers are generally allowed to participate in higher education on a part-time basis, but I believe some countries restrict them from full-time enrollment since that could be inconsistent with their working full time.  I do not know the situation in Portugal.

Comment: Thanks @phoog !
So, basically if I find a job in another Schengen country, I will have to apply for a residence permit for that country. Right?

Comment: @user6083264 yes (perhaps unless the Portuguese permit is a blue card, but I don't know too much about the blue card and I assume that an application under art. 88(2) would not result in a blue card -- I could be wrong about that, though).